# Laravel Is Not updating values while using ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to update the value of a column but its now working.
I am trying this to update views on the page but its not happening.
There is no error Still its not updating in the database.
View page

```
    <form style="" name="fbCommentCountform" id="fbCommentCountForm" action="{{ url('/posts/{$display_post->id}')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">

    <input type="text" name="commentCount" id="fbFormCommentCount">
    <input type="text" name="visitCount" id="hiddenFormPostVisitCounter" value="{{ $display_post->visit_count }}">
  </form>
```

Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $image = $request->file('featured_img');
  $posts = Post::findOrFail($id);
  if(!empty($image))
  {

    $name = str_slug($request->title).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $destinationPath = public_path('/public/images');
    $imagePath = $destinationPath. "/".  $name;
    $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
    $posts->featured_img = $name;
   }
  $posts->title = $request->title;
  $posts->body = $request->body;
  $posts->slug = $request->slug;
  $posts->categories_id = $request->category;
  $posts->description = $request->description;
  $posts->visit_count = $request->visitCount;
  $this->validate($request,[
    'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'body' => 'required'
  ]);
  $posts->update();
  return redirect('posts');
```

Now here is the ajax Code

```
<script>
  let fbCommentCount = document.getElementById('fbCommentCount').getElementsByClassName('fb_comments_count');
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('fbFormCommentCount').value = fbCommentCount[0].innerHTML;

  var $formVar = $('#fbCommentCountForm');

  let visitCount = document.getElementById('hiddenFormPostVisitCounter').value;

  let visitCountPlusOne = parseInt(visitCount) + 1;
  document.getElementById('hiddenFormPostVisitCounter').value = visitCountPlusOne;

  $.ajax({
    url: $formVar.prop('{{ url('/posts/{$display_post->id}') }}'),
    method: 'PUT',
    data: $formVar.serialize(),
  });
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

If someone could help me to solve this problem

Comment: Check the response for validation errors

Answer (score 0):

Better practice is to use method `route()` instead of `url()`.
You should call your variable `post`. It's single element, but back to the main point. You validate wrong. In your request you don't have variables: `title` and `body` and Validator returns error before updating data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will not work but check first:

- Your route must be "PUT"
- Will be better if you in `update` use `$post` instead of `$posts`. You are requesting only one post ;)
- In view use named routes instead of urls. In future will be better to manage everything without searching where you used it :)
- Change `$posts->update();` into:

  ```
  if ($post->isDirt()) {
      $post->save(); //Notice that here i am using save instead of update
  }
  ```

Could you please provide to us your request from ajax? I am what body you are sending? If you are sending files you need to use `multipartdata` form. Look here:
[What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)